# How to get Web.config file in the root of a create-react-app project to copy to the build folder so it gets archived and deployed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, create-react-app

I have a file copy task in my build to copy the Web.config in the root of my create-react-app project folder, and it shows that it is copying it to the build file after the yarn build task completes.

But it is never in the archived folder.  How do I modify this build or copy files task to get this `Web.config` file into my build folder so that it can get archived and dropped for release?

[image]

I copy it from the $/repo dir/app folder to build (yarn build step creates the build folder)....but the Create release package that archives the build folder does not contain it in the produced zip.

[image]

[image]

Here's a screenshot of my folder structure in my repo (what's in the $/repo dir/app folder):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Copy task you need to specify full path of the `build` folder, for example:

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/build
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to copy it either.  It's still not making it into the release package.  The build log indicates it completed the step, but it isn't there - log message: Copying D:\a\9\s\[app root folder]\Web.config to D:\a\9\s\build\Web.config

Comment: Ok, so as it turns out, the target folder needed to be $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/[app root folder]/build because of how my particular folder structure is - I have a root app folder, then the build folder in that - but I believe your solution is what would apply to this case in most instances ...and what was also needed was to change the project directory for the Yarn Install and Yarn Build tasks to be $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/[app root folder], and then the Create Release Package task to use $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/[app root folder]/build as well.  After that, it all worked.

Answer (score 2):

Include the ***web.config*** file in the `public` folder

Now the file gets included in the build and dropped for release

Comment: Stuck down here with 0 votes when I found it, THIS is the solution Worked perfectly. Thanks @abu

Answer (score 0):

Because you have coded all the paths, I can’t analyze this issue according to your specific situation.

You can specify the Web.config file from `...` to see if it can be successfully copied to the build folder.

[image]

It would be much easier for people to investigate further and reply if you could attach detailed file path and logs.